Retrieve results from JSON array using Java RestAssured JsonPath
String jsonResponse = """
[
    {
        "vi": ["Khoá đào tạo miễn phí", 4],
        "en": ["Free training courses", 4]
    },
    {
        "vi": ["Miễn phí giao hàng", 2],
        "en": ["Free delivery", 2]
    }
]
""";

From the JSON response above I need to get the values of the key "vi" then store them in a List<Map<String, Object>>.
I've tried using $..vi in https://jsonpath.com/ and got the correct result.
When trying the Java code below, however, I always get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "vi" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function.
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from(jsonResponse);
List<Map<String, Object>> perks = jsonPath.get("$..vi");

I do know that RestAssured in Java uses Gpath notation but I'm stuck on how to get my code working.
I'm using Java RestAssured and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json.

can you share the dependencies you used explicitly

Hi @Hagelslag, I used


org.json
json
20240303



io.rest-assured
rest-assured
4.4.0

Sorry I didn't do enough background reading on the Jackson API so I included it in the question. From what I have just gathered, I should be able to get what I want by directly using
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from(jsonResponse); List<Map<String, Object>> perks = jsonPath.get("<the correct path>"); without Jackson API.
So yeah I'm merely looking for the correct path

I've just removed Jackson API from the question.

I've tweaked my code a bit and finally achieved the desired results.
List<List<String>> perks = jsonPath.getList("collect {it.vi}");


It would be nice for the community if you could improve and elaborate on your answer.
